# How to use the Google Closure Compiler to optimize Kotlin JS

Tags: google-closure-compiler, kotlin-js

Is it possible to use the Google Closure Compiler to minify Kotlin JS code further than what Webpack offers? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should declare an NPM dependency on the Closure Compiler ([latest version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-compiler)):

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation(devNpm("google-closure-compiler", "20210808.0.0"))
}
```

Then, create a task that will run after webpack minification:

```kotlin
tasks.create<Exec>("compileWithClosure") {
    // browserProductionWebpack: production minified version by Webpack
    // kotlinNodeJsSetup: needed to execute Node scripts (':' because it is on the root project)
    dependsOn("browserProductionWebpack", ":kotlinNodeJsSetup")

    // Get the Node installation directory
    val kotlinNodeJsSetup = rootProject.tasks["kotlinNodeJsSetup"] as org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.nodejs.NodeJsSetupTask
    workingDir = File(kotlinNodeJsSetup.destination, "bin")

    // Execute the script
    commandLine(
        "node",
        "${File(rootProject.buildDir, "js/node_modules/google-closure-compiler/cli.js")}",
        "--js=${File(buildDir, "distributions/<your module name here>.js")}",
        "--js_output_file=${File(buildDir, "distributions/optimized.js")}",
        "-O=SIMPLE",
        "--env=BROWSER",
        "--warning_level=QUIET",
    )
}
```

[Full list of arguments](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler):

- `-O=ADVANCED` seems to break the Kotlin generated file (at least in my case with Kotlin JS 1.5.21 IR)
- `-O=SIMPLE` removes ~600kB from the binary (2.1MB → 1.5MB, using Kotlin React, KotlinX.Serialization & Ktor)
- `--warning_level=QUIET` because we are passing an already-minified file, console output is completely unreadable, and actually slows down compilation